# How to run tests using the Rascal jar without using REPL?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, rascal

I am trying to run my test suite outside the repl! I tried to go for something like this without success:

```
java -Xmx1G -Xss32m -jar rascal-shell-unstable.jar TestSuite.rsc -v :test
```

How can I run my test suite and get the same output of running :test inside the repl just by running the jar?

Answer (score 2):

There is no builtin way to do this, so for now I'd recommend using a bash script (if you are in a bash-like shell:

```
cat << ENDCAT | java -jar rascal.jar
import TestSuite;
:test
:quit
ENDCAT
```

If you are not in such an bash environment, you'd have to write a similar script which pipes the REPL commands through the rascal.jar shell program.

Accidentally I was working today on JUnit integration for Rascal tests, so that's coming up soon.